# Function for adding rows if they aren't already present from a unique list/csv?

Tags: python, parsing, multiple-columns, rows

I downloaded a .csv file with columns: Genus, species, Region, and Distribution. (image below).

[image]

Each Genus + species has a different variation of Regions, none exactly the same, and in Distribution it says 'Present' in every single row because the species are all present.

I created a list of unique regions in my dataframe called unique_regions (and a .csv file containing a single column of all regions in my dataset).  This file also has the corresponding Latitude and Longitude for each unique region.

My goal is to use this unique_regions variable (or .csv file) to systematically go through each Genus + species and add the countries that were not included (or in other words, not present) into the Region column and then add 'Absent' into the Distribution column.

For example:
Here is a species that is only present in 20 Regions of the world (out of the 324 total unique regions I have in my list):
[image]

I need there to be 304 new rows (just for this species alone), with same Family, Genus, and species entry.  The regions that were not included should be added along with the corresponding Latitude and Longitude from the unique_regions list or .csv file, and next to those regions it should say 'Absent'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you turn the file into a python list first, you could do something like this:

```py
List = [{"Family":"family name here","Genus":"genus name here","Species":"species name here"}] 
#This list contains all of the information from your file. With this
#script, each entry is a dictionary so that you can access a column by going:
#
#item = List[Index_Number]
#data_you_need = item["type of data you need"]
#
#However, you could also just use a list and remember which list index corresponds
#to which kind of data

item = List[0]

for i in range(304):
  List.append({"Family":item["Species"], "Genus":item["Genus"],
                      "Species":item["Species"]}
#This bit here uses the keys that you define to access each type of data,
#grabs the data entered in the previous entries, and copies it into a new
#entry.
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
# load csv with species
df = pd.read_csv('./Erysiphaceae_combined/Thekopsora_areolata.csv')

# load csv with unique regions
unique_regions = pd.read_csv('./unique_regions.csv')

# add all unique_regions to Region column of df, replace NA values with desired values
combined = pd.concat([unique_regions,df],sort=False)
combined['Family'] = combined['Family'].replace(np.nan,'Erysiphaceae')
combined['Genus'] = combined['Genus'].replace(np.nan,'Thekopsora') #HERE
combined['Species'] = combined['Species'].replace(np.nan,'areolata') #HERE
combined['Distribution'] = combined['Distribution'].replace(np.nan,'Absent')
combined = combined.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Region',keep ='last')

# write new csv with desired outputs
combined.to_csv("./Kriging/Thekopsora_areolata.csv")
```